# How to call pure virtual functions in dll from exe application?

Tags: visual-c++

I have a dll which has an abstract class with all of its member functions are pure virtual functions. I am trying to write an application to call these functions. What are the steps I need to take to call these pure virtual functions?

This is a just a prototype

Header file with abstract class : interface.h [These are the exported functions]

```
class MathFuncExport {

public:

    virtual int Add(int a, int b)=0;

    MathFuncExport(){};
    virtual ~MathFuncExport(){};
};
```

Header file in dll : MathFuncDll.h

```
#include "intf.h"

class MyMathFuncs : public MathFuncExport
{
public:
    MyMathFuncs(){};
    virtual ~MyMathFuncs(){};
    virtual int Add(int a, int b);
};
```

Implementation : MyMathFunsDll.Cpp file

```
#include "MathFuncDll.h"

int MyMathFuncs::Add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

This created a dll but I am not able to call the functions in abstract class or I am missing some link here. Please help me in resolving this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Apply the __declspec(dllexport) attribute to both classes so they get exported.  If you want to hide the concrete class then you'll need a class factory.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call pure virtual. They are implemented to force function(s) implementation.
Since your base class is in the DLL you have to export class in order to use it for deriving other classes.

The easiest way to export class is to use implicit linking; this way you need a header for the class declaration and import library. For overllok of the different linkages [check this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yd93633).

For a little demo create Win32 dll. Check MFC support if you need it and check the Export Symbols box.

This will create a dll with sample class and global variable export. Look at the header file where special macro is created, having different meaning for DLL (export) and executable linking with this dll (import).

Once you understand how to use implicit linking, you will be able to derive class from the base class in the dll as if you were using code in the executable module.

Comment: I read an article which details out on how to call pure virtual functions or abstract class. Check out this link                           http://tweakbits.com/articles/dll/index.html